# firestore rest url works on browsers but not on mobile device

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

i just enter the standard request url on browsers and simply i get the answer. its the url :
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject/databases/(default)/documents/products/1ZFMrY2iw9a554Ltz6Bu

but when i use it on flutter project i receive the below answer:

> I/flutter (10824):    I/flutter
>   (10824):    I/flutter (10824):
>   Error 403 (Forbidden)!!1 I/flutter (10824):

i write my code like this:

```
Future<http.Response> Request({String inputURL,httpMethod method}) 
{

Map<String,String> headers =  
{

};

  switch (method) {

    case httpMethod.gett:
       return http.get(inputURL,headers: headers);
      break;
    case httpMethod.head:
   return http.head(inputURL,headers: headers);
      break;
    case httpMethod.post:
  return http.post(inputURL,headers: headers);
      break;
    case httpMethod.put:
       return http.put(inputURL,headers: headers);
      break;
    case httpMethod.delete:
     return http.delete(inputURL,headers: headers);
      break;
    case httpMethod.connect:
  //return http.(inputURL);
      break;
    case httpMethod.options:
     //return http.op(inputURL);
      break;
    case httpMethod.trace:
       //return http.trace(inputURL);
      break;
  }
```

Comment: It's showing the 403 forbidden error, so there's a possibility that its an auth issue. You might be able to access it on the browser since you're logged in the console, while you're unable to get it from the device because you have no session there. Try accessing the same link (`https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject/databases/(default)/documents/products/1ZFMrY2iw9a554Ltz6Bu`) in incognito and see if it works from there?

Comment: @AL. thanks for answering i get the same 403 error

Comment: You're welcome. So it is an auth issue. I haven't worked on flutter before, so I can't comment on anything specific. You just need to be able to authorize your request or (note: this is not usually done for security purposes, I strongly suggest that you don't do it this way) set your firestore *security rules to public*.